# Any reference that explains generated equivalence relation

Tags: reference-request, elementary-set-theory

Im looking for a reference that characterizes when an equivalence relation can be generated from a relation and gives a clear explanation of it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Recall that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Generating_equivalence_relations) the equivalence relation generated by a relation is the smallest equivalence relation containing it. Equivalently, the equivalence relation $S$ generated by a relation $R$ is such that $(x,y)$ is in $S$ if and only if there exist $n\geqslant0$ and $(x_k)_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ such that $x= x_0$, $y = x_n$, and for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, either $(x_{k-1},x_{k})$ or $(x_{k},x_{k-1})$ belongs to $R$.

Since every equivalence relation is generated by itself, for every equivalence relation there exists a relation generating it.

To get $R\subseteq S$ generating $S$, one can erase from $S$ some or all of the following: (1) every $(x,x)$, (2) either $(x,y)$ or $(y,x)$ for every $x\ne y$ such that $(x,y)$ is in $S$, (3) every $(x,y)$ such that $(x,z)$ and $(z,y)$ are in $S$ for some $z\ne x,y$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would still prefer a reference though as I don't want to go through all the "rigorous" details by myself and just cite a reference (preferably not wikipedia). One thing is missing is the following: Why is S generated by the relation explained in the second sentence of your first paragraph the smallest such equivalence relation? How did the characterization came to be? Im sure those are easy to prove but I don't want to go through it myself if they can be found somewhere else.

Comment: Any equivalence relation containing R is stable by reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity hence it must contain every such (x,y). On the other hand, the relation S thus defined is an equivalence relation hence S is the smallest equivalence relation containing R. No other reference (sorry).

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see why the relation $S$ (which is supposed to be the equivalence relation generated by $R$) is reflexive. What if $x$ is an element of the set such that for all $(y,z)\in R$, $y,z\neq x$, i.e., $x$ does not appear as a coordinate in any element of $R$? Then it seems that $(x,x)\notin S$.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell, yes $S$ is always reflexive. Here is a hint: one can choose paths $(x_k)_{0\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ of length $n=0$.

Comment: So by allowing $x=x_0$ to be a path, the condition for $x_0Sx_0$ is vacuously satisfied?

Comment: Well, for $x=y$ and $n=0$ it is satisfied that $x_0=x\land x_n=y\land \forall k\in[1,n], \dots$. The latter one being vacuously true.

Answer (score 2):

No one actually gave a reference so I'll add one.

The book Introduction to topological manifolds by John M. Lee explains this at some length in the appendix A. Also, he gives good examples of generated equivalence relations in Chapter 3, Quotient Spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can also see easily without an explicit construction that the intersection of all equivalence relations containing $R$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: But looking at your question, I suppose you wanted something more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Did's answer gives a direct explicit characterization, but you can also break it up into three steps that correspond to the defining properties of an equivalence relation:

1. Relate every element to itself, to make sure the relation is **reflexive**.
2. Whenever $x$ is related to $y$, relate $y$ to $x$, to make sure the relation is **symmetric**.
3. Directly relate elements that are connected by a chain of relations, to make sure the relation is **transitive**.

In a bit more detail, letting $X$ be a set and $R$ a relation on $X$:

1. Take the **reflexive closure**: for every $x \in X$, add $(x, x)$. We obtain a relation $R_1$.
2. Take the **symmetric closure** of that: for every $(x, y) \in R_1$, add $(y, x)$ to the relation. We obtain a relation $R_2$.
3. Take the **transitive closure** of that: for every finite path of related elements $x_1 \mathrel{R_2} x_2 \mathrel{R_2} x_3 \cdots \mathrel{R_2} x_n$ (meaning $(x_1, x_2), (x_2, x_3), \ldots \in R_2$), add $(x_1, x_n)$ to the relation. We obtain a relation $R_3$.

Then, the relation $R_3$ we end up with is the equivalence relation generated by $R$.
If you unpack each of the steps, you will see that an arbitrary pair in $R_3$ will have the form explained in Did's answer.

---

### Observations

Note that step 1 and step 2 can be interchanged.
But step 3 must be the last one.

If you want, step 3 can be broken down further into a countable number of steps so that the definition of transitivity appears more evidently:

- Start with $R_{3, 0} = R_2$.
- Given $R_{3,n}$, for any two pairs of the form $(x, y), (y, z) \in R_{3,n}$, add $(x, z)$. We obtain $R_{3, n + 1}$.

Note that this step might not terminate in a finite number of steps, in the sense that it might be that, for any $n$, after completing the step above, the relation is still not transitive. (Indeed, consider starting with the relation $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to \cdots$) But if we consider the union $R_3 = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} R_{3, n}$, this will be the transitive closure of $R_2$.

Also note that we can merge steps 1 and 3 into one if we include paths of length zero, i.e. paths consisting of a single element.
But then this wouldn't coincide with the notion of transitive closure (smallest transitive relation containing the given relation): for example, the transitive closure of the empty relation is the empty relation, while this procedure would yield the relation $\{(x, x) \mid x \in X\}$.
Perhaps we could call it the "[preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder) closure".